# Export/Import RSA key pair from web app

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, service-worker

I want to encrypt messages in chat rooms (web app) in a way that it wouldn't be possible for anyone to decrypt them except for the receivers. It seems that RSA encryption is a good way. Each user (actually, each device) would have a public-private key pair and each message would be encrypted with the receiver public key and decrypted with the receiver private key, so each message should be sent as many times as receivers for the same.
I've found a [tutorial](https://blog.patricktriest.com/building-an-encrypted-messenger-with-javascript/) which explains how to achieve that goal. The encryption/decryption is calculated in a Service Worker and the private key is not exposed, just stored in the same worker.

However, I wonder if there would be a secure way of exporting the key pair from a device to be able to see your messages from another device.
I could add a `messageType` called `"exportKeys"` and retrieve both keys like in the bellow example:

*From the above tutorial adding "exportKeys" messageType and function:*

```
self.window = self // This is required for the jsencrypt library to work within the web worker

// Import the jsencrypt library
self.importScripts('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsencrypt/2.3.1/jsencrypt.min.js');

let crypt = null
let privateKey = null

/** Webworker onmessage listener */
onmessage = function(e) {
  const [ messageType, messageId, text, key ] = e.data
  let result
  switch (messageType) {
    case 'generate-keys':
      result = generateKeypair()
      break
    case 'encrypt':
      result = encrypt(text, key)
      break
    case 'decrypt':
      result = decrypt(text)
      break
    case 'exportKeys':
      result = exportKeys(key)
      break
  }

  // Return result to the UI thread
  postMessage([ messageId, result ])
}

/** Generate and store keypair */
function generateKeypair () {
  crypt = new JSEncrypt({default_key_size: 2056})
  privateKey = crypt.getPrivateKey()

  // Only return the public key, keep the private key hidden
  return crypt.getPublicKey()
}

/** Encrypt the provided string with the destination public key */
function encrypt (content, publicKey) {
  crypt.setKey(publicKey)
  return crypt.encrypt(content)
}

/** Decrypt the provided string with the local private key */
function decrypt (content) {
  crypt.setKey(privateKey)
  return crypt.decrypt(content)
}
/** Export keys */
function exportKeys (publicKey) {
  return {
    publicKey: publicKey, 
    privateKey: privateKey
  }
}
```

Then, I could show a QR or whatever to the user to export his keys to another device and let him do the opposite from the new one with something like `"importKeys"`.

Although this may work, I'd be exposing the private key with `"exportKeys"` as well in the client side. But would it be a security issue if you don't really send the private key through the internet?

Any other tip about it?

Comment: Maybe use one-time access token / key to (encrypt and) sync the real key? so at lease the real key won't be seem directly (by a screen recorder or something)

Comment: What version of PHP you use? If PHP 7.2 then i would advise you to use `sodium` functions and more specifically `sodium_crypto_box` http://php.net/manual/en/function.sodium-crypto-box.php

Comment: @PeterDarmis Only Javascript is involved here.

Comment: @Manolo sorry my bad then... In that case you could use NaCl.js https://github.com/tonyg/js-nacl for the same functionality or use any libsodium implementation in javascript in github you are comfortable with.

Comment: @PeterDarmis Do you mean, like appleapple, to encrypt the private key before exporting it and require a key for importing it?

Comment: @Manolo no i meant libsodium library i think it has the same functionality as the one you use. Using a Service Worker is great, but why bother export the keys? Prompt the user to encrypt both keys using a phrase of his/her choice. When on other device decrypt using that phrase.

Comment: @Manolo In case you can interact with the Service Worker from that page, pass the user phrase to your Service Worker and retrieve the encrypted by pass-phrase keys. Also please read this https://gist.github.com/atoponce/07d8d4c833873be2f68c34f9afc5a78a#asymmetric-encryption and use something different than RSA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `private` and `encrypted` messages perhaps you could use a libsodium implementation in javascript such as [js-nacl](https://github.com/tonyg/js-nacl), or [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium.js?files=1) for implementing `Public-key authenticated encryption using crypto_box`. Most of the functionality is similar to the one you already use. To explain better:

Sender and recipient must have a set of keys (***public*** and ***private***) in order to encrypt/decrypt messages.

Sender needs the `sender-PrivateKey` and `recipient-PublicKey` and `nonce` to encrypt a message.

Recipient needs `recipient-PrivateKey` and `sender-PublicKey` and `nonce` to decrypt the message.

Example code is taken from js-nacl Github readme page.

```
senderKeypair = nacl.crypto_box_keypair();
recipientKeypair = nacl.crypto_box_keypair();
message = nacl.encode_utf8("Hello!");

nonce = nacl.crypto_box_random_nonce();
packet = nacl.crypto_box(message, nonce, recipientKeypair.boxPk, senderKeypair.boxSk);

decoded = nacl.crypto_box_open(packet, nonce, senderKeypair.boxPk, recipientKeypair.boxSk);

"Hello!" === nacl.decode_utf8(decoded); // always true
```

> I want to encrypt messages in chat rooms (web app) in a way that it
>   wouldn't be possible for anyone to decrypt them except for the
>   receivers. It seems that RSA encryption is a good way.

I don't know if RSA encryption is a good way. According to what is considered best tactic [Cryptographic Best Practices - Asymmetric Encryption](https://gist.github.com/atoponce/07d8d4c833873be2f68c34f9afc5a78a#asymmetric-encryption) it is better to use libsodium(NaCL) functions for encryption than RSA.

Last thing asked is how to export keys without revealing them?

You could export the keys using [`nacl.crypto_box_seed_keypair(Uint8Array)`](https://github.com/tonyg/js-nacl) and user provided input (to convert to Uint8Array use [nacl.encode_utf8(String)](https://github.com/tonyg/js-nacl#naclencode_utf8string--uint8array)).

> ***nacl.crypto_box_seed_keypair(Uint8Array)***
>
> - Produces an encrypted authenticated box keypair from its argument. A
>     given binary input will always produce the same keypair as output.
> - The input may be of any length. The input is hashed once with sha512,
>     and the first 32 bytes of the result are taken as the 32-byte secret
>     key, which is then passed to nacl.crypto_box_keypair_from_raw_sk.